# add Scrollview inside Layout+Viewpager + listview it is possible?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

- i am trying to add  Layout+View pager +list view,Layout+View pager working fine but View pager inside recycler view not scrolling.
- it is possible...guide me 
  -Advance thanks

[requirement Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f22xg.png)

- How Can i set viewpager an recyclear view height dynamically
- my xml code ...

  ```
  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/imageView3"
      android:background="@drawable/profile"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="27dp" />



  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
      android:id="@+id/tabs"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      app:tabMode="fixed"
      app:tabGravity="fill"
      app:tabTextColor="@color/your_unselected_text_color"
      app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/your_selected_text_color"
      android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/viewpager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tabs"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

  </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

  </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
  </LinearLayout>
  ```

Comment: why would you use a list view instead of a recyclerview ? plus try instead of using a scroll view a nested scroll view from the support library

Comment: tq for replay@Seaskyways and umair mansuri..please chck edited my question

Answer (score 0):

First of all copy this class file in your project

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ExpandableHeightListView extends ListView {

boolean expanded = false;

public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public boolean isExpanded() {
    return expanded;
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (isExpanded()) {
        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
    this.expanded = expanded;
}
}
```

Then use the ExpandableHeightlistview in scrollview like this

```
<ScrollView ...>
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <viewpager></viewpager>
    <com.example.ExpandableHeightListView ... />
    <other view items />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then setadpater of listview 
and lastly and very important listview.setExpandable(true)